# Where is the toilet smoke detection indication displayed for a B777-200/300?

Tags: safety, boeing-777, display, smoke-detectors

In case of smoke detected in any of aft toilet of a B777-200/300, where is the indication displayed? Is this at a single location, or at different locations?

Answer (score 3):

From the 777 manual:

> Each lavatory has a single smoke detector. If smoke is detected, an aural alert
>   sounds in the lavatory and in the cabin. In addition, the lavatory call light
>   flashes and the master call light at the associated attendant station illuminates.
>   The EICAS advisory message SMOKE LAVATORY indicates smoke is detected in
>   one of the lavatories.

The EICAS is a display in the cockpit.

It is treated as a fire, and the cabin and flight crews follow the set procedures to handle it.